# EU workforce per commune

Tags: data-request, europe, census, population

For a project I need geodata of communes with residential population and workforce (optimally also full-time equivalents, FTE) for at least FR, DE, IT, and AU.

On Eurostat and EU Data Portal websites I managed to find geodata for census regions (2011) and communes (similar, but not identical) as well as the Census Hub, where at least in theory it seems I can obtain residential population per commune. (I filed a data request with the interface for the data for FR, DE, IT, and AU, but the job hasn't completed after several hours; I suspect there's an error.)

However, **I couldn't find data on workforce (and/or FTE) per commune anywhere.** In Census Hub it seems to me the data may be available for [NUTS3](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/nuts/overview) regions but not at a finer scale. Does anybody know where such data may be available, at EU level or per country?

Comment: I would guess that it's easier to find **un**employment per commune or region, although this can't easily be combined with population because it doesn't take into account children, disabled and retired.